# Pbkdf2 - To/FromBase64String - Different Bytes

Tags: .net, authentication, password-encryption

I'm trying to write a custom authentication process.  I'm using these 2 functions - 1 to create encrypted passwords and 1 to check the password against what the user submits

When I run the latter and try to use the FromBase64String it gives me different bytes than the ToBase64String that ran on create

```
        private string passwordCreator(string Password, byte[] salt = null, bool needsOnlyHash = false)
    {
        
        if(salt == null || salt.Length != 32)
        {
            salt = new byte[256/8];
        }

        using(var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        }

        string pw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                            password: Password, 
                            salt: salt, 
                            prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256, 
                            iterationCount: 100000, 
                            numBytesRequested: 256/8
                        ));

        if(needsOnlyHash) return pw;

        return $"{pw}:{Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}";
    } 
    private bool passwordChecker(DimUser user, string Password)
    {
        string pw = user.UserPw; 
        string salt = user.Salt; 

        var saltedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

        if(user.Salt == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        var passwordSubmitted = passwordCreator(Password,saltedByte,true);

        if(String.Compare(pw, passwordSubmitted) == 0)
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
        
    }
```

This is using .net 5

Comment: Andrew

Thank you for the reply.  The Base64-encode is used in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/consumer-apis/password-hashing?view=aspnetcore-5.0 which is why I used it

The rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt) converts the array from all 0s to having non-zero values.  It automatically (I think) updates the passed in parameter

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using

```
using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
{
    rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
}
```

in your method body. This is taking whatever you have in your salt and replacing it with a new salt value which I do not think you want.

Here is what I came up with based on what you have that works for me

```
void Main()
{
    var clearPassword = "P@ssw0!d";
    var salt = new byte[32];

    using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
    {
        rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
    }

    var encryptedPassword = passwordCreator(clearPassword, salt);

    Console.WriteLine(encryptedPassword);

    var result = passwordChecker(new User { Salt = Convert.ToBase64String(salt), Password = encryptedPassword }, clearPassword);

    Console.WriteLine(result);

}

public string passwordCreator(string Password, byte[] salt)
{
    if (salt == null || salt.Length != 32)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    string pw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                        password: Password,
                        salt: salt,
                        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
                        iterationCount: 100000,
                        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
                    ));

    return pw;
}

public class User
{
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Salt { get; set; }
}

public bool passwordChecker(User user, string Password)
{
    string pw = user.Password;
    string salt = user.Salt;

    var saltedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

    if (user.Salt == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var passwordSubmitted = passwordCreator(Password, saltedByte);

    if (String.Compare(pw, passwordSubmitted) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Also if you wanted to stay closer to what you original had I came up with the following. This only uses the salt when one is not supplied. Just have to be careful with this implementation as it could cause you heartburn if used incorrectly.

```
void Main()
{
    var password = "P@ssw0rd";

    var passwordWithSalt = passwordCreator(password);

    var passwordWithSaltParts = passwordWithSalt.Split(":");

    var result = passwordChecker(passwordWithSaltParts[0], passwordWithSaltParts[1], password);

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

private string passwordCreator(string Password, byte[] salt = null, bool needsOnlyHash = false)
{

    if (salt == null || salt.Length != 32)
    {
        salt = new byte[32];

        using (var rngCsp = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            rngCsp.GetNonZeroBytes(salt);
        }
    }

    string pw = Convert.ToBase64String(KeyDerivation.Pbkdf2(
                        password: Password,
                        salt: salt,
                        prf: KeyDerivationPrf.HMACSHA256,
                        iterationCount: 100000,
                        numBytesRequested: 256 / 8
                    ));

    if (needsOnlyHash) return pw;

    return $"{pw}:{Convert.ToBase64String(salt)}";
}

private bool passwordChecker(string pw, string salt, string Password)
{
    if (salt == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    var saltedByte = Convert.FromBase64String(salt);

    var passwordSubmitted = passwordCreator(Password, saltedByte, true);

    if (String.Compare(pw, passwordSubmitted) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }

    return false;

}
// You can define other methods, fields, classes and namespaces here
```